# How can I copy a table from one database to another database along with its data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two separate databases installed on the same server. I name the representation as db1 and db2. I have a table named `sample_table` in my db1 database. I am trying to copy this table with its records to my db2 database with the following queries:

`CREATE TABLE db2.sample_table LIKE db1.sample_table`

`insert into db2.sample_table select * from db1.sample_table`

As a result of my research, I found that this method works in most places. However, when I type and run my query from the db2 console, I am having a user permission problem for db1. The query might be running, but should there be a configuration link between these two databases? If so, how can I get this link? What are the alternative solution methods I can overcome this problem?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`. Of course, only base structure will be copied, without triggers/foreign keys/etc.

Comment: *when I type and run my query from the db2 console, I am having a user permission problem for db1.* What is "db2 console"? What is precise permissions problem error message?

Comment: Hello. I wanted to mention the area where I query for 'Db2' database tables. Since I want to copy the above CREATE and INSERT query from the Db1 database to the Db2 database, I run the query in the area where I write the queries for my Db2 database.

Comment: Are these 2 databases within the same MySQL instance? Or are you  trying to copy between 2 different MySQL instances

Comment: *I wanted to mention the area where I query for 'Db2' database tables.* What is "the area where I query for 'Db2' database tables"? Do you use some third-party client software?

Comment: *when I type and run my query* You show 2 separate queries. Does 1st fails? Or it succeed, but 2nd fails?

Comment: If you have access denied message, then there is not much you can do from a programming point of view. You need to make sure the same user has appropriate access to both databases.

Comment: @Akina I am using the DataGrip IDE to write queries. A separate console screen appears for querying the Db1 database, and a separate console screen for querying the Db2 database. On the screen where I write a query to the Db2 database, I want to run the above queries and copy the semple_table table in my Db1 database to the Db2 database.

Comment: Does `SHOW DATABASES;` executed in both windows shows both databases db1 and db2 in output lists? Does `SHOW TABLES FROM db1` and from `db2` shows correct tables lists in both windows?

Comment: Does `select @@server_uuid;` returns the same value in both windows?

Comment: @Akina When I run `SHOW DATABASES' in the console I opened for the Db1 database, it shows Db1. When I run `SHOW DATABASES` on the console screen for Db2, it shows Db2.

Comment: @Akina Yes when I ran `select @@server_uuid;`  it showed the same output in both windows.

Comment: If so then compare `SELECT current_user();` and `SELECT user();`.

Comment: @Akina Yes Db1 database and Db2 database usernames look different. This problem can be solved when I define the user login information to which I connect to the Db1 database to the Db2 database and log in. I will try and come back.